# Как заголовок Set-Cookie полученный post-запросом установить во главе последующих запросов используя retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit2

Из post-запроса я получила заголовок Set-Cookie. Как мне отправить его при выполнении последующих запросов используя Retrofit2?

```
@GET("/user")
    Call<User> getUser(@Header("Cookie") String Cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример инициализации Retrofit, использующего OkHttp с автоматическим сохранением кук и добавлением их к запросам.

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager))
                .build()
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(...)
                .addConverterFactory(...)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
```

требуется: `implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.9.1'`
или создание класса аналогичного [JavaNetCookieJar](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-urlconnection/src/main/java/okhttp3/JavaNetCookieJar.java)